# Calculation in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am using below in SSRS expression. Basically calculation is based on two text fields in SSRS report as below. I am still getting error in case when 
`ReportItems!Amount6.Value` have no value or record.

`=iif(reportitems!Amount.Value = 0 or reportitems!Amount6.Value = 0 or Len(reportitems!Amount.Value) <= 0 or Len(reportitems!Amount6.Value) <= 0, NOTHING, (ReportItems!Amount.Value - ReportItems!Amount6.Value) / ReportItems!Amount6.Value)`

`=iif(reportitems!Amount.Value = 0 or reportitems!Amount6.Value = 0 or Len(reportitems!Amount.Value) <= 0 or Len(reportitems!Amount6.Value) <= 0, NOTHING, (ReportItems!Amount.Value - ReportItems!Amount6.Value) / ReportItems!Amount6.Value)`

Comment: why don't you do it through the dataset rather calculated field?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: I already did on dataset like this "isnull(Amount,0) Amount". But still getting error

Comment: Gives me "#Error" like this

Comment: I'm going to guess that you need to make sure the `ReportItems!` is capitalized correctly.  SSRS can be picky about little things like that.  Are each of the report items you're referencing calculated using multiple fields or could you simply refer to them as `Fields!Amount.Value` or whatever they may be called from the query?

Comment: Thanks for all your help. But I end up with using code as below Public Function MyDivider(top As Double, bottom As Double) As Double
    If top = 0 Then Return 0
    If bottom = 0 Then Return 0
    Return top / bottom
End Function              And this is the code I am using fro each calculation =Code.MyDivider((firstvalue - secondvalue),Fields!periodheadcount.Value)

Comment: try iif(cdec(ReportItems!Amount6.Value) = 0,nothing, ((cdec(ReportItems!Amount.Value) - cdec(ReportItems!Amount6.Value)) / cdec(ReportItems!Amount6.Value)))

Answer (score 0):

IIF is a Function, not flow control

so every parameter gets executed, if you want to divide conditionally, you have to set the divider to 1 when its nothing or zero, and return nothing when divider is nothing or zero, also you can use cdec(expression) to convert to decimal, that way you dont have to deal with the nothing cases

```
=iif(cdec(reportitems!Amount.Value) = 0 or cdec(reportitems!Amount6.Value) = 0 or Len(reportitems!Amount.Value) <= 0 or Len(reportitems!Amount6.Value) <= 0, NOTHING, (cdec(ReportItems!Amount.Value) - cdec(ReportItems!Amount6.Value)) / iif(cdec(ReportItems!Amount6.Value) == 0,1,cdec(ReportItems!Amount6.Value)))
```